# Composition in c++

Tags: c++

I know the basic idea of composition that the composition has "have" relationship.But when it came to implement the idea of composition something went wrong ,Till now i didn't figure out the object and constructor call of another class in the base class.
Please help me on this regard.

Comment: What do base classes have to do with composition?

Comment: Are you after the syntax for calling member object constructors? Then this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 1):

Composition means that the contained class object does not exist beyond the lifetime of the outer class(which contains it) object.

**[Online Sample](http://ideone.com/fbFGS):**

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(){std::cout<<"\nMyClass";}
        ~MyClass(){std::cout<<"\n~MyClass";}
};

class MySecClass
{
    MyClass obj;
    public:
        MySecClass(){std::cout<<"\nMySecClass";}
        ~MySecClass(){std::cout<<"\n~MySecClass";}
};

int main()
{
    MySecClass obj;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> MyClass
>   MySecClass
>   ~MySecClass
>   ~MyClass